# Request.auth.metadata in security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firebase project where I'd like for users to be able to see when other users created their profiles. My initial hope was that I could use "user.metadata.creationTime" on the frontend to pass the date into the user's extra info document and verify that it is correct by having "request.resource.data.datecreated == request.auth.metadata.creationTime" as a Database Rule, but it looks like it is not possible according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request).

Is there any way I can verify that the creation date is correct on the backend?

**More info edit**: Below is the code that is being triggered when a user creates a new account on my profile. The three values are displayed publicly. I'm creating a niche gear for sale page so being able to see when a user first created their account could be helpful when deciding if a seller is sketchy. I don't want someone to be able to make it seem like they have been around for longer than they have been.

```
    db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        username: "Username-156135",
        bio: "Add a bio",
        created: user.metadata.creationTime
    });
```

Firestore rules:

```
 match /users/{id} {
  allow get;
  allow create, update: if request.resource.data.username is string &&
    request.resource.data.bio is string &&
    request.resource.data.created == request.auth.metadata.creationTime;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more clear about what you're trying to achieve? I can't tell exactly what the condition is that you're trying to check, nor under what condition.  I suggest showing both the rule and the client code together that don't work the way you expect.  Rules are meaningless without client code to allow or deny.

Comment: Details are added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.metadata.creationTime`, according to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.UserMetadata#creationtime) is a string with no documented format.  I suggest not using it.  In fact, what you're trying to do seems impossible since that value isn't available in the [API documentation for request.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth).

What I suggest you do instead is use a [Firebase Auth onCreate trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) with Cloud Functions to automatically create that document with the current time as a proper timestamp.  Then, in security rules, I wouldn't even give the user the ability to change that field, so you can be sure it was only ever set accurately by the trigger.  You might be interested in [this solution overall](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07).