# What is the best way to implement a trial mode in Firebase based on the time the user was created?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am refactoring my current trial mode since I am switching to Stripe. Stripe comes with its own custom claim. My current trial logic, as of now, was based on a Firebase timestamp and looks like this,

```js
admin
          .auth()
          .getUser(uid) // Note : .getUserByEmail(tokenData.email!) you can use this as well
          .then((user) =>
            admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
              userType: userType,
              trialUntil: // time stamp when the user is created
              stripRole: 'trial', // This is for the stripe role
            })
          ),
```

Is there a way I can access the date a user was created from the user metadata and check against it based on my preferences in the rules? My issue with the current implementation is that I don't want to have a custom claim that will be used only once and then be stuck with it for the user's lifetime.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310323/request-auth-metadata-in-security-rules.